# Creating a Stack Overflow notifier

Tags: android, cookies, notifications

I could not find a Stack Overflow notifier Android app so I am planning on making one.  I hope that my app will serve a similar purpose as the [Stack Overflow Notifier Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/djioipahfnmmhddmnanoicecpnfomned).  This will be my first Android app so I am still unfamiliar with the platform.

So I currently plan to ask the user to login by bringing up a `WebView` and then access the *Recent Activity* page in the background at specific intervals.

**My question:**
How can I store the authentication cookie from StackOverflow after the user has logged in through the `WebView` and then send this cookie in the `HttpGet` request when accessing the *Recent Activity* page?

Comment: There is already an app in android that works with SO. Check the market.

Comment: @Marcase: The only SO app that I found was SOflair and it serves a different purpose.  SOflair is a widget that shows a user's SO badge.  I would like to make a notifier app that notifies upon changes to the Recent Activity page, which requires being logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow is challenging because there is no username and password - you need to be able to allow the user to login fully with their OpenID setup.

An embedded browser where you can read the StackOverflow cookie would be the best choice.